# Ember how to access a child controller from a parent controller

Tags: javascript, html, controller, ember.js, frontend

I have a list of people and I'd like to show how many records are being edited using **Ember.js**. Inside PeopleController, I'm trying to count the attribute **isEditing** from PersonController with the following code:

```
Schedule.PeopleController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({ 
    editCounter: function () {
        return this.filterProperty('isEditing', true).get('length');
    }.property('@each.isEditing')
});
Schedule.PersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
        isEditing: false
});
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting 0 as a result from **editCounter** function. This  attribute (**isEditing**) should tell me how many people are being edited. The function **editCounter** is called inside the **html** archive that I called index.html:

```
...
            {{outlet}}
            <div id="count_edits">
                <span id="total_edits">
                    <strong>Editing: </strong> {{editCounter}}
                </span>
            </div>
...
```

So here is my question: How would I access correctly **isEditing** inside **PeopleController**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your ArrayController ensure you are setting the itemController:

```
Schedule.PeopleController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({ 
    itemController: 'Person',
    editCounter: function () {
        return this.filterProperty('isEditing', true).get('length');
    }.property('@each.isEditing')
});
```

See http://jsbin.com/eyegoz/4/edit